# PostgresPagingQueryProvider retuns 0 columns

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch

I have a `PostgresPagingQueryProvider` that has a simple query

```
Select id from action
```

This is expected to return 1 column. When I run the batch I have an exception saying

```
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT id FROM action WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1000]; 
The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

This is the query provider:

```
@Bean
public PostgresPagingQueryProvider queryProvider() {
    PostgresPagingQueryProvider provider = new PostgresPagingQueryProvider();

    HashMap<String, Order> sorting = new HashMap<>();
    sorting.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
    provider.setSelectClause("Select id");
    provider.setFromClause("from action");
    provider.setWhereClause("where 1=1");
    provider.setSortKeys(sorting);
    return provider;
}
```

And this is the creation of the table

```
CREATE TABLE action (
id int4 NOT NULL,
"timestamp" timestamp NULL,
CONSTRAINT action_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

When using the same query with `ItemReader` this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out.

The problem was that due to a copy paste of mine I setting the first variable of the query to `STOPPED` .

As someone might notice the query **does not accept any parameters**. So deleting that fixed the issue.

In addition to that I thought that the part where I pass in the HashMap of the variables was unrelated, thus it is not included in the question so I guess no one could have answered that.

I am going to leave this here as a tribute to the monumental errors and time wasting a copy paste might lead.